# Opening a file from other directory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7

I have a tkinter python file saved in a folder on the directory. The icons and other resources are for the file are saved in another folder.

```
root_directory
|
|---resources
|   |
|   |---icon.png
|
|---windows
|   |
|   |---tkinter_file.py
```

In `tkinter_file.py`, I want to set an icon for the tkinter window. So, I did something like:
`root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='../resources/icon.png'))`

But, this shows up an error:
`_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "../resources/icon-appointment.png": no such file or directory`

Please help me out to successfully locate the PNG file located in a different folder.

Comment: It refer to your project path,not file path when you run your code.Try `"resources/icon.png"`.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. Same error occurred. @jizhihaoSAMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the relative path to `icon.png` from `__file__`, which is the path to your current source file:

```
import os
thisdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rcfile = os.path.join(thisdir, '..', 'resources', 'icon.png')
```

then

```
...  root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file=rcfile))
```

Comment: Thanks! That error has been removed now. But, a new error has occurred now. It says: `_tkinter.TclError: can't use "pyimage8" as iconphoto: not a photo image` @AbbeGijly

Answer (score 1):

If you use relative path, you're at the mercy of your current working directory, which may not always be `(...)/root/windows`.  Most likely your current directory is wherever you are executing your Python executable/shell.  You'll want to use absolute path or update your current directory:

```
import os
os.chdir('(...)/root_directory') # fill in your absolute path to root_directory
```

An inelegant method would be to change the directory to wherever your current `.py` file is and then work your way back:

```
cur_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(os.path.join(cur_dir, '../resources/icon-appointment.png')
```

The more proper way would be to run your script as a module so it retains project structure.